# Android - How to reference activity that registered receiver in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

In my MainActivity I have:

```
this.registerReceiver(new SmsListener(),new IntentFilter("RECEIVED SMS"));
```

In my manifest.xml I have:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.example.SmsListener">
```

and in my BroadcastReceiver subclass I have:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // how do I reference MainActivity here?

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get activity from Context. If you really need it, I guess your only option is to save the reference of your MainActivity in a private static field and then make a static "getInstance()" method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static MainActivity sActivity = null;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sActivity = this;
        ...
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return sActivity;
    }
    ...
}
```

From your receiver you can now call

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        MainActivity myMainActivity = MainActivity.getInstance();
        ...

    }
}
```

However, I don't think you want to do it.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work since I can't use most of MainActivity's methods.

Comment: And what if you replace Activity by MainActivity ? I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent i = new Intent (context, MainActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(i);

}
}
```

Comment: I don't want to start the Activity I want to call one of its methods.

Comment: did you try **MainActivity m = new MainActivity(); m.methode();**

Comment: I need a reference to the existing instance.